# Custom, conditional redirect on logout

Tags: redirect, logout

I'd like to implement a custom logout function that only runs if the conditions are met. Instead it returns me to the homepage whether the conditions are true or not.
Here's the code that should do the logging out:

```
function no_cookie() {
    global $noCookiesLeft;
    if($noCookiesLeft) {
         wp_redirect("mysite.com/custom logout");
         exit;
     }
}
add_action('wp_logout','no_cookie',10,2);
```

And here's the code that should trigger this:

```
if($cookie_count >= 3) {
    wp_delete_user($id);
    $noCookiesLeft = true;
    wp_logout();   
}
```

noCookiesLeft is a global variable since I haven't found any other way to do this, and google failed me.

Edit:

```
function login_cookie($user_login, $user) {
global $wpdb;
global $noCookiesLeft;
$id = $user->ID;

if(!isset($_COOKIE['userCookie'])) {
    if(in_array('administrator', $user->roles))
        $wpdb->delete('wp_cookies',['user_id'=>$id]);

    $cookie_count = $wpdb->get_var("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM wp_cookies WHERE user_id=".$id."");
    if($cookie_count >= 3) {
        wp_delete_user($id);
    }
    else {
        $value = md5($id);;
        setcookie('userCookie', $value, time()+360000*24*100, "", "",false);
        $wpdb->insert("wp_cookies",[
                    'user_id'=>$id,
                    'cookie_value'=>$value
                ],
                [
                    '%d',
                    '%s'
                ]);

        }
     }
 }

add_action('wp_login','login_cookie',10,2);

function no_cookie() {
    wp_redirect("/error);
    exit;
}
 }
  add_action('delete_user','no_cookie',10,2);
```

Comment: `wp_cookies` isn't a Core table. Is this a table  you've created?

Answer (score 0):

You need to be sure that you have noted global $noCookiesLeft; before setting it in the if statement. It may be unset when it runs the no_cookie() function.

Comment: The variable is initialized to false right before the function.

Comment: Does the user still get logged out by wp_delete_user if the wp_logout line is removed? Would it make more sense then to use the deleted_user hook?

Comment: I haven't really thought about that, I'll try it.

Comment: It worked... sort of. It's redirecting now, but won't log the user out. I can't add wp_logout after wp_redirect, can I?

Comment: Not in that same location, it will never reach the line. Could you put wp_logout() into the function called by the wp_delete_user hook, followed by the redirect? Sorry, I'm usually more concise with a correct solution but it's not enough of the code to test live.

Comment: I'll edit my post and add the rest of the code.

Comment: Also it now no longer deletes user from the database.